# Is the motion of rotation perfectly symmetrical?

Tags: reference-frames, orbital-motion

Scientifically, can we say that one of these assertions is more "correct" than the other? (philosophically we can say that the first one is more correct because it makes the motion of other planets "simpler" to express)

Because of gravitation, the Earth is turning around the Sun.

Because of gravitation, the Sun is turning around the Earth.

(I want to keep the question open on all the specifities on the frames of reference (Galilean or not)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an exhaustive discussion [here](http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2005/10/03/does-the-earth-move-around-the-sun/).